# Why are there only 2 solutions for $x^n=1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

(where $n>0$)

I have been taught that an equation with the highest power $n$ will always have $n$ solutions. This does not appear to be the case with:
$$x^n=1 \implies x=\pm1$$
Where $n$ is even, the solutions are $1$ and $-1$; where $n$ is odd, the only solution is $1$.

Why? Is it a special case, or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: It has $n$ solutions, but only one or two of them are *real*. The rest are complex numbers. The full set of solutions can be written $x = \cos(2\pi k/n) + i \sin(2\pi k/n)$ for $k=0,1,2,3,\ldots, n-1$.

Comment: Polynomial equations on the real numbers have *at most* as many solutions as the degree. But they can have none, for instance $x^2+1=0$.

Comment: You've gotten it backwards - there is only one real solution when $n$ is odd, and two if even.

Comment: If OP is asking this question, I think he has still to learn about rings, fields, etc. I think mentioning stuff like that will confuse him more than help him.

Comment: Thanks, @ThomasAndrews. Will edit.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD I understand that $\Bbb R$ represents the reals, and what complex numbers are; but I have no idea what a ring or a field is. Most of my higher maths knowledge is based on questioning teachers and maths.SE, so there are many holes to fill in.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, my comment was referring to the guys answering, mentioning more complicated stuff like that. To be very brief, the "field of real numbers" refer to the "3-tuple" $(\Bbb R, +, \cdot)$; that is, the real numbers coupled with the standard multiplication and addition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you speek about solutions of an equation you must *always* be careful about the **"algebraic structure"** (In a specialistic language Fields/Rings) where you are searching a solution.

For example, searching a solution in $\mathbb{Z}$ is not equal to searching a solution over $\mathbb{Q}$ even in very simple cases.

An interesting example of this phenomenon is the polynomial $2x-1$.

The related equation has no solution in the ring $\mathbb{Z}$ but a unique solution in $\mathbb{Q}$ (that is in specialistic language $\mathbb{Z}$'s fraction field).

Looking more closely to your case, given a polynomial with just one variable (a so-called "univariate polynomial") of degree $n$, its associated equation has  always $n$ solution in (the field) $\mathbb{C}$ but it can have no solution in -(the field) $\mathbb{R}$

Look for example to the polynomial $x^2+1$.

Algebra in some sense is the study of this differences, but something sure are the following theorems:

> **Theorem** Let $p(x)$ be a univariate polynomial of degree $n$. Then there always exist a "bigger" algebraic structure (called *the splitting field of the polynomial p*) where the equation $p(x)=0$ has exactely $n$ solutions (counted with multiplicity)

For example, in a case above, the field $\mathbb{C}$ is the splitting field of $x^2+1$ over $\mathbb{R}$

Well, to conclude, let's speack about $\mathbb{C}$.
It is a very "beautifull" algebraic structure because has a very nice property:

> **Theorem** Let $p(x)$ an univariate polynomial of degree $n$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{C}$. Then $p(x)=0$ has exactely $n$ solution over $\mathbb{C}$ (counted with multiplicity)

In particular, since $\mathbb{R} \subset \mathbb{C}$, a real polynomial is a complex polinomial and its associated equation has always $n$ complex solution but cannot have $n$ real solutions.
This is precisely the case of $x^2+1$.

There are "not many" algebraic structure with the same property of $\mathbb{C}$.
This kind of structures are called "algebrically closed fields" and are one of the most important objects of Algebra.

Comment: You just used the terms "field", "ring", and "univariate" casually in a response to somebody presumably in high school algebra

Comment: You're right. I hope now it's more clear to a high scool student

Comment: @JosephCurwen I can now understand quite a lot of that, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It has $n$ roots, but only if you consider [roots $x_i\in \Bbb C$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E16%3D1). These "special" ones are calleds the *roots of unity*.

As an example, consider $X^4=1$; try to check that $X_1=i$ is a root of said equation.

Answer (score 1):

The statement that there are always $n$ solutions is only true if you are working in the field of complex numbers. In the field of the real numbers this is not true, as you have shown.

Please note, that even in the field of complex numbers, a solution can occur multiple times, i.e. $(x-1)^2$ has a double zero at $1$. In that case, you need to define how you count the number of solutions.

Comment: So, you can have multiple solutions that are actually the same number?

Comment: @Mutantoe well yes, that depends on the definition - if we take the multiplicity into account, then we have always $n$ complex solutions for a polynomial of degree $n$. If we do not care about multiplicity, then there can be less.

Answer (score -3):

Notice, we have $$x^n=1$$ $$x=(1)^{1/n}$$ $$=(\cos 0+i\sin 0)^{1/n}$$ $$=(\cos 2k\pi+i\sin2k\pi)^{1/n}$$ $$=\left(\cos \left(\frac{2k\pi}{n}\right)+i\sin\left(\frac{2k\pi}{n}\right)\right)$$ Thus there are $n$ roots which can be determined by setting $k=0, 1, 2, \ldots (n-1)$

Comment: I think this is wrong. By definition, $(1)^{1/n}$ is always $1$ and not something else

Comment: Here, we are considering complex roots. Could you please tell me why $1=\cos 0+i\sin 0$ not true in complex numbers ?

Comment: $1 = \cos 0 + i \sin 0$ is true, but thats not what i meant.

Comment: You made two mistakes. the first is from the first to the second row: counterexample: $x=-1,n=2$, then $-1 = x = (1)^{1/2} =1$, which is obviously wrong. The second mistake cancels the other out and is in the last row: there is no mathematical law that you can take roots like that

Comment: Do you know de moivre's theorem? See the result in the first comment above.

Comment: yes, i do know de moivre's theorem. do you apply it here? i don't think you do. And what is wrong with my proof $-1 = 1$ ?

Comment: You are right, I didn't say you are wrong so far.

Comment: **Supinf** is right, $1^{1/n}=1$ always so the second and third equality are not equivalent to the first one. Like for example, $\sqrt{4}=2$ and not $\pm 2$. But if $x^n=1$, then $x=e^{\frac{2ik\pi}{n}}$, $k=0,...,n-1$.

Comment: I know you're using De moivre's theorem and you definitely know how it works, but Supinf's point is that your notation is not correct.