# solutions for $x^n = 1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm supposed to solve this in terms of $n$, a natural number.

I'm really getting tripped up on this, and I don't really know why. The only way this can have a solution is if $n = 0$, specifically the algebra I wrote to show this is

$
\begin{gather*}
x^n = 1\\
\log_x(x^n) = \log_x(1)\\
n\log_x(x) = 0\\
n = 0
\end{gather*}
$

So, does this mean there are infinite solutions or just one unique solution? I'm not sure how this would change using $x$ as a complex number.

Comment: The second to last line tells you that $n$ is $0$ OR that $\log_x x = 0$. That second condition is satisfied by $x = 1$...except that $1$ isn't a valid base for logarithms. *Assuming* that you can take $log_x$ of both sides *assumes* that $x = 1$ is not a solution...but it is.

Comment: Hint: Roots of unity.  Google it.

Comment: Except $\log_x(x)$ is not always defined.

Comment: When it comes to complex numbers, do you even have a good definition of $\log$, or more importantly, $\log_x$ when $x$ is not a positive real number? One thing is clear: this method doesn't do the whole job, for $i^4 = 1$, so that's a non-$1$ solution for $n = 4$.

Comment: Or even real numbers, since $(-1)^2=1$, @JohnHughes

Comment: I understand the roots of unity, but when I tell my professor "Well, because for each n there is n distinct roots (1 has 1, 2 has 2 (-1, 1)....), I would say that there are infinite solutions for $x^n = 1$" I'm told that I'm not answering what the question is asking

Comment: I suspect that the prof wants you to say "for each specific $n$, there are $n$ roots, which are ...." (and then you write out a formula that gives the $n$ different roots).

Comment: You're supposed to solve this *in terms of $n$*.  That is, $n$ is a fixed integer.  There are not infinitely many solutions to $x^5 = 1$, and likewise there are not infinitely many solutions for $x^n = 1$ for any fixed $n$.

Comment: Check this link out: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1398501/why-are-there-only-2-solutions-for-xn-1

Comment: Just because $1^n=1$, it does not mean $n=0$.

Comment: My issue is that I was thinking x could be *any* number. I don' think I asserted that $1^n = 1 \Rightarrow n = 0$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured out where I was getting hung up. I was thinking $x$ would be any number and that $n$ meant infinity (I gotta stop doing that!?)

So my thought process was like "Oh, if $n = 5$ then I have 5 solutions, but if $n = \infty$ then I have infinity solutions so that means there are infinity solutions for $x^n = 1$ this was super flawed :( Honestly, it seems like the question is a little wild.

So, for any kids who might stumble upon this question with the same ????? I had on my face - $n$ is just some number. Consider the easy fact that when $x \in \mathbb{R}, x^n = 1$ has one solution when $n$ is odd, and 2 solutions when $n$ is even (think about this!)

Add in the complex numbers and now you're looking at roots of unity which tells us.... what? ;) Check out those patterns too. if I choose $n = 5$ how many solutions are there for $x^5 = 1$ with $x \in \mathbb{C}$?

Everyone gave great hints, I think I just didn't really know what I needed to know until I knew it.

Feel good knowing that it (hopefully) didn't take you two days of back and forth's with a mathematician to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear. You say that you are solving this "in terms of $n$, a natural number. The following doesn't give you all the details, you will need to figure out what the question is actually asking before you write down your solution.

First question is: What is your definition of natural number? Or to put it differently, is $0$ a natural number. Let me assume that it is.

Second question is: Is $x$ a constant and you are solving for $n$ or is $n$ a constant and you are solving for $x$?

Case 1a: $x$ is positive constant not equal to $1$ and you are solving for $n$. In this case the only solution is $n=0$. For all other $n$, $x^n \neq 1$.

Case 1b: $x =1$ and you are solving for $n$. Here any $n$ will work.

Case 1c: $x$ is a negative constant and you are solving for $n$. In this case you have $x = -y$ for some positive $y$. So $x^n = (-1)^ny^n$. For this to be $1$ you need $(-1)^n = 1$ (otherwise the whole thing is negative because $y^n$ is always positive). This is satisfied exactly for the even numbers (including $0$). Then you need $y^n = 1$. If $y =1$, then this is true for all $n$ and your solution set is the set of all even $n$. If $y\neq 1$, then $n=0$ is the only solution.

Case 2a: $n$ is a constant (natural number greater than $0$) and you are solving for $x$. Let's assume that we are looking for solutions in the complex numbers. Here the solution set is know as the $n$th roots of unity. If
$$
x_0 = e^{2\pi i/n}
$$
The the so $n$ solutions are
$$
x_0, x_0^2, \dots, x_0^{n}.
$$
If you are just solving within the real numbers, then you only get those (from the list) that are real. This will be $-1$ and $1$. You only get $-1$ when $n$ is even.

Case 2b: $n=0$ and you are solving for $x$. In this case the solution set is all real (or complex) numbers except $0$. While some are going to disagree with me on this, $0^0$ is commonly not defined. (Just ask your teacher what convention you use in the class.)

---

Note here the case where you are solving for $n$ and $x\neq 1$ is a positive constant. In this case we got that $n=0$. And here *your solution is actually correct*! (within the real numbers.)

Answer (score 0):

\begin{gather*}
x^n = 1\\
\log_x(x^n) = \log_x(1)\\
n\log_x(x) = 0\\
n = 0
\end{gather*}

Line 1: Okay. Solutions are $e^{\frac{2\pi in}{k}}$, $k=1,2,\dots,n$

Line 2: You can only take base $x$ if $\mid x\mid\neq 1$.(Why*)

Line 3: Same, You can only take base $x$ if $\mid x\mid\neq 1$.

Line 4: No problem then. (Why**)

(*) (showing only for real $x,y$): Note that $\log_x y=\dfrac{\ln y}{\ln x}$, diverges to $\infty$ if $x=1$ since $\ln 1=0$ and undefined when $x=y=1$

(**) Note it is basic indices rule that $x^n=1\Rightarrow n=0$ iff $\mid x\mid\neq 1$, since let $x=re^{i\theta}$, then $x^n=r^ne^{in\theta}=1\Rightarrow r^n=1$(since $e^{in\theta}=1$ since imaginary part is $0$ and $r\neq 0$). Then $n=0$, since $r\neq 1$.

For example $2^n=1\Rightarrow n=0$.